# EXCEL.EXE Running even after i use excelObj.Quit(); in activexscripts

Tags: excel, activex, excel-2010, activexobject

Since, I could not find any satifying answer on the web for this question, I put forth it in Stackoverflow. I use activexscript to manipulate Excel, Outlook. But, even after I `runexcelobj.Quit()` at the end, I see an EXCEL.EXE still running in the task manager.

I tried using `excelobj.Application.Quit()` (as mentioned by some post in stackoverflow)also did not resolve the problem.

Can somebody help me with this??

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way the application goes away in JScript:

```js
// WScript.CreateObject for cscript.exe or wscript.exe
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");

// ...

excel.Quit();
// null out EVERY reference to Excel objects
excel = null;
CollectGarbage();
```